# Import a javascript file in Vue compoment

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a project using Laravel and vue js and I needed to import a js package name ( photojshop ) ", which enable to edit an image filter or color " in my vue component.

I tried this way :

```
<template>
<img src=".." id="myImg" >
</templete>


<script>
  import $ from 'jquery'
  export default {enter code here
    data: () => ({
      ......data of your component
    }),
    mounted() {
      let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
      recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', 'my local js file')
      document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
    },
    methods: {
      EditImage(){
        $('myImg').photoJshop({ .... }) (error)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

but when I call the function  `$('..').photoJshop({})` an error occur function is not defined (photoJshop)

Comment: *when I call the function* - this is not listed in the code.

Comment: You should either install this 3rd party library as an NPM package in your project (and then use **import** to get access to its methods) - or include it as a SCRPT tag in your `./public/index.html` file. Usually such libraries do not have an NPM package - so only option 2 will be available to you.

Comment: did you import jquery and jquery ui too?

Comment: I edited the article => i added how i did call the function photoJshop and the import of jquery into the component

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes there is no NPM package , can you explain more the option 2 pls ?

Comment: Well, you simply edit your `index.html` and put there the `<script src="full_url_to_jshop.js">` and whatever other scripts this JShop depends on.

Comment: Well , I've added `<script src="{{asset(full_url_to_jshop.js)}}">` in my welcome.blade.php , the component.vue understands the fonction but when i exécute the console log that this function is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved i just needed to write my code in

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
           ....
        })
```

so that